# Trimmomatic bug -baseout (and other optional parameters)

Tags: cluster-computing, bioinformatics

I have been struggling with some odd behavior with Trimmomatic v.0.33 run on an HPC when trying to use the -baseout argument.

My code looks like:

```
java -jar /path/to/trimmomatic-0.33.jar PE input_fastq_1.fq input_fastq_2.fq \
-baseout mybaseoutname ILLUMINACLIP:TruSeq2-PE.fa:2:30:10 LEADING:3 TRAILING:3 SLIDINGWINDOW:4:15 MINLEN:36
```

Trimmomatic would run but the output file names would, bizarrely, be derived from other parts of my script (e.g., .fq, ILUMINACLIP, LEADING:3). Any ideas for how to fix this besides explicitly stating the output file names?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution to this bug is to specify any option parameters (i.e., those with a minus tag) *before* required parameters like input files and trimming steps.

Rearrange the parameters like this and it should run fine:

```
java -jar /path/to/trimmomatic-0.33.jar PE -baseout mybaseoutname
input_fastq_1.fq input_fastq_2.fq ILLUMINACLIP:TruSeq2-PE.fa:2:30:10 LEADING:3 TRAILING:3 SLIDINGWINDOW:4:15 MINLEN:36
```

Tony Bolger (creator of Trimmomatic) explained this bug on seqanswers: http://seqanswers.com/forums/showthread.php?t=46572&highlight=trimmomatic+baseout